# Updating to a newer macOS version - how can I avoid potential pitfalls?

Tags: macos, mojave, upgrade

I'm running a Macbook Pro with macOS 10.7 Lion. I've already checked and it can be upgraded to the latest macOS version (Mojave). However, I want to keep as much as I can running the same (like applications), and I don't particularly care about which OS that I upgrade to. What should I look out for before I upgrade?

And if it turns out that upgrading would block me from using certain applications, would upgrading **and also** keeping a separate partition of macOS Lion be viable solution?